# JavaScript Object constructor not showing stable value

Tags: javascript

I have a js code as follows,

```
   function findDealerByIdResponse() {
findDealerByIdResponse.prototype = findDealerByIdResponseType;


this.getPrefix = function(){
        return "tns1";
};
this.getNS = function(){
    return "http://www.hp.com/bookservice";
};

} 

function findDealerByIdResponseType(){
var DEALER ;


this.getPrefix = function(){
        return "tns1";
};
this.getNS = function(){
    return "http://www.hp.com/bookservice";
};


}

function getName( obj ) { 

   var funcNameRegex = /function (.{1,})\(/;
   var results = new Object();
   results = (funcNameRegex).exec((obj).constructor.toString());
   return (results && results.length > 1) ? results[1] : "";
};

function test(){
var req = new findDealerByIdResponse();
alert(getName(req));
}
```

But If i perform "test" first time it is giving what i expected : "doTransactionType" . But afterwards it is giving "Function" . Please explain the reason.

Thanks

Deepak

Comment: What do you mean by `afterwards` ? Add more info what you did.

Comment: I repeatedly invoked the method test using a submit button..

Comment: There is something else, only with your code posted, the result won't change.

Comment: Agree with xdazz: you haven’t posted all your code; as posted it works fine.

Comment: actually prototype usage was there.

Comment: I have edited the code. Kindly have a look. The usage of prototype seems to be the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the first call to `findDealerByIdResponse`, you set its `prototype` property to a function, namely `findDealerByIdResponseType`. As a result, `.constructor` will be overwritten by this assignment, and it will resolve to the constructor of that function - which is, as any function, `Function`.

Instead, you want this:

```
// set prototype to a parent instance
findDealerByIdResponse.prototype = new findDealerByIdResponseType;

// restore .constructor
findDealerByIdResponse.prototype.constructor = findDealerByIdResponse;
```

You'd want to place it after the declarations of both functions.

Comment: For more information, try reading this article: ["Constructors considered mildly confusing"](http://joost.zeekat.nl/constructors-considered-mildly-confusing.html). The key sentence: _Remember that: the only objects that in fact have a constructor property by default are the automatically created prototype properties of functions._

Comment: Oh, and actually, there’s no need for the second line; I think the point of the getName exercise was to illustrate that assigning the **new** `findDealerByIdResponseType` prototype would also change the object's (prototype's) `constructor` property.